# About return lambda expressions

Tags: java

I can't understand what does the method return mean, and I don't know where the builder and name come from

```
@ConditionalOnBean(DecompressorRegistry.class)
@Bean
GrpcChannelConfigurer decompressionChannelConfigurer(final DecompressorRegistry registry) {
    return (builder, name) -> builder.decompressorRegistry(registry);
}
```

GrpcChannelConfigurer class :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface GrpcChannelConfigurer extends BiConsumer<ManagedChannelBuilder<?>, String> {
@Override
default GrpcChannelConfigurer andThen(final BiConsumer<? super ManagedChannelBuilder<?>, ? super String> after) {
    requireNonNull(after, "after");
    return (l, r) -> {
        accept(l, r);
        after.accept(l, r);
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Method return means that a method will return either a value or a reference depending on the type. If the type is primitive it will return value itself and a reference for any type other than the primitives. Means that you can then get the value or reference after a method finishes its execution.

Answer (score 1):

The `BiConsumer` interface looks like this:

```
public interface BiConsumer<T, U> {

    /**
     * Performs this operation on the given arguments.
     *
     * @param t the first input argument
     * @param u the second input argument
     */
    void accept(T t, U u);
 ...
}
```

The code `(builder, name) -> builder.decompressorRegistry(registry);` is an implementation of `accept`. It is equivalent to writing:

```
class MyGrpcChannelConfigurer implements GrpcChannelConfigurer {

  void accept(ManagedChannelBuilder builder, String name) {
    builder.decompressorRegistry(registry)
  }
}
```

Saying `return (builder, name) -> ...` is equivalent to `return new MyGrpcChannelConfigurer();`